# How can I verify if a checkbox is selected using TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, automation, testcafe

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture("TestCafe Example")
    .page("http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example");

test("Fill out and submit form", async t => {

    await t.typeText("#developer-name", "Harun Jonuzi");
    //I Want to verify if these Checkboxes are Selected
    await t
        .click("#remote-testing")
        .click("#reusing-js-code")
        .click("#background-parallel-testing");


    await t.click("#macos");

    const preferredInterface = Selector("#preferred-interface");
    await t
        .click(preferredInterface)
        .click(preferredInterface.find("option").withText("JavaScript API"));
        

    const submitButton = Selector("#submit-button");
    await t
        .expect(submitButton.hasAttribute("disabled")).notOk();

    await t.click(submitButton);

    const headerInfo = Selector("#article-header");
    await t.expect(headerInfo.innerText).eql("Thank you, Harun Jonuzi!");
})
```

My question is commented out on the 6th line of the code as you can see it.
I am trying o figure out how to add an assertion to verify that the checkboxes are actually checked, but I am new to TestCafe, just wanted to see If I can get some help from here.

Comment: If the supplied answer helped you solve your problem please reward the person who supplied it by accepting it (click the check).  Otherwise please provide information on why it did NOT solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `checked` property of [the DOMNodeState Object](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402670/reference/test-api/domnodestate#properties-1), for example:

```js
await t
    .click("#remote-testing")
    .expect(Selector('#remote-testing').checked).eql(true);
```